# Invoke getting Thread was being aborted

Tags: vb.net

I am getting an error and crash on my app from an invoke with ThreadAbortException "Thread was being aborted"
how can I still call the function but not crash?

I am running Lightstream to stream data from a server using live stream into my vb.net app so the OnUpdate is what triggers the call

```
Public Sub OnUpdate(itemPos As Integer, itemName As String, update As IUpdateInfo) Implements IHandyTableListener.OnUpdate

    Dim sResult As String = "Case: " & update.ItemPos.ToString & " - " & Environment.NewLine & update.ToString

    Call Process_Data_Call(update.ItemPos.ToString, sResult)
End Sub

Private Delegate Sub Process_Data_Delegate(iItemPos As String, sResult As String)
Private Sub Process_Data_Call(iItemPos As String, sResult As String)
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.Invoke(New Process_Data_Delegate(AddressOf Process_Data_Call), New String() {iItemPos, sResult})
    Else
        'functions go here
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What's in the `Else` block?  Is it just updating the UI?  I'd be inclined to first try calling `BeginInvoke` instead of `Invoke`.

Comment: thats correct, its updating the UI.

Comment: Show us the code!  Obviously it's updating the UI.  The point was is it JUST updating the UI.

Comment: yes it puts the response data from the server into a TextBox1.Text